# Button state is not updated using RelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

My application is using MVVM Light toolkit. This is the command, which is bound to button in XAML:

```
    private RelayCommand _buttonCommandNew;
    public RelayCommand ButtonCommandNew
    {
        get
        {
            var worker = new TCService();
            return _buttonCommandNew
                   ?? (_buttonCommandNew = new RelayCommand(async () =>
                   {
                       var progress = new Progress<string>(status =>
                       {
                           ProgressText = status;
                       });

                       await worker.GenerateConfiguration(1, "", "", progress);
                   }, () => !worker.InProgress
                ));
        }
    }
```

This is the service:

```
class TCService : ITCService
{
    public Task<bool> GenerateConfiguration(int cellCount, string templateFilePath, string outputFilePath, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => RunConfigurator(progress));
    }

    public bool InProgress { get; private set; }

    private bool RunConfigurator(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        InProgress = true;
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        progress.Report("Yeah!");
        InProgress = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is the button to be disabled when the service start to work and enable it at the end. This is not happening with current implementation. What is more important, to do it with comply to MVVM Light. I feel like my service should be inherited from one of the base clases in MVVM Light and I need to use `Set` in order to notify UI about change. But not sure if I am on right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the `InProgress` property to the view model (the class which contains the `ButtonCommandNew` property) and which is bound to the UI.

Then, In the setter of the `InProgress` property you can call [ButtonCommandNew.RaiseCanExecuteChanged](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/404e779f-7c2b-875f-bf17-b8ad84bfb7ef.htm) which is going to notify that the UI to call `CanExecute` on the `_buttonCommandNew` `RelayCommand` and hence either enable or disable the button in the UI depending on the value of the `InProgress` property.

In this case you need to set the `InProgress` property to `true` before you call `worker.GenerateConfiguration` and then reset it to `false` after you're done calling the method.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick, but I thought CanExecute is somehow observable by `RelayCommand` and I just need to propagate change with `Set`.

Comment: The event CanExecuteChanged from ICommand is observed by the UI and once it is raised the UI will requery CanExecute to determine whether to enable or disable the button (or whatever is bound to the command).

Comment: I still want to understand why it doesn't work "out of box". This is very common pattern to enable/disable button in response to command execution. `CanExecuteChanged` is raised by `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`, this is clear. But `canExecute` itself should be observed for change in my opinion. On top of `RelayCommand` in src code I see the following comment: `IMPORTANT: Note that closures are not supported at the moment due to the use of WeakActions`. Do you think it's related?

Comment: This is how the WPF folks designed it to work, you raise CanExecuteChanged to notify the source (typically the UI) about a change in execution capability of the command. The source determines the execution capability by calling CanExecute and then updates its user interaction capability. I don't think the support for closures has to do with this simply because the ICommand contract is irrelevant of whether you're using RelayCommand from MVVM Light or any other implementation of the ICommand interface.